git describe and git log ignoring tag filters
I am trying to make a script which reads all commits since the last release tag in my repository. For reference, I am locked into using git version 2.46.0 because this is on an azure devops host.
So the last few commits on my repository look like this
eeeee Commit 5
ddddd Commit 4 (tag: other-tag)
ccccc Commit 3 
bbbbb Commit 2
aaaaa Commit 1 (tag: iteration-1.0.0)
...

I first run git fetch --tags and run git tags -l to verify that all the tags I am expecting are present as well as git checkout main to make sure I am not in a detached head state.
But when I run git describe --abbrev=0 --match="*iteration*" it says that it cant describe eeeee. And when I run git log iteration-1.0.0..HEAD it only returns eeeee and ddddd. It seems like git is unable to look past the "other-tag". When I delete "other-tag", I get the data that I am expecting on both commands.
I have tried running these commands on the same repository on my dev machine, and the problem isn't there. Is it a bug with git?

Is that a shallow clone?

At first I didn't think so, but the first step of ADO does a git fetch with depth=1. Adding --unshallow to my git fetch fixed it. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as solved.

@eftshift0 Socratic approach done right.

@spectacularbob, Have tried the options fetchDepth: 0 and fetchTags: true on the checkout task in your pipeline as suggested in my answer below? Are they working for you?

You are working on a shallow clone... Being that the case, git is missing a lot of information working locally.

on Azure DevOps, in the classic build pipelines or in the non-deployment job of YAML pipelines, it will automatically add the default checkout task to clone/check out code from the source repository.
By default, the checkout task:

Does not fetch tags (fetchTags: false).
Shallow fetch is configured with a depth of 1 (fetchDepth: 1).


For your case, you can disable the Shallow fetch on the checkout task and also set it to fetch tags in your pipeline:

If your pipeline is YAML pipeline, you can configure the checkout task like as below.
# azure-pipelines.yml

jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    fetchDepth: 0   # Disable the Shallow fetch. Equivalent to '--unshallow' option.
    fetchTags: true  # Fetch tags. Equivalent to '--tags' option.

  . . .


If classic build pipeline, enable "Sync tags" option and disable "Shallow fetch" option on the web UI.



Related Azure DevOps documentations:

steps.checkout definition
Shallow fetch
Sync tags


